# Kotlin falses colors on custom view (paint)

Tags: android, kotlin, user-interface

I tried to set colors programically for Paint library. And when I set colors, everything looks normal, like here:
[image: setting the colors]

But when I draw on the canvas with these set colors, every color except black becomes kinda purple, like this:
[image: Falsed Colors]

Everything looks normal, and causes no crashes. How to solve this? Any help appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use this function [`ContextCompat.getColor()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/core/content/ContextCompat#getColor(android.content.Context,int)) to retrieve the color :

```kotlin
java-static fun getColor(context: Context, id: @ColorRes Int): @ColorInt Int
```

It will return:

> A single color value in the form 0xAARRGGBB.

So for example, if you would like to set color to brown, instead of having just the resource ID `R.color.brown`, use the following:

```kotlin
ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.brown)
```